# How to increase width of code block in WordPress blog?

Tags: block-editor, code

I am new to writing blogs on WordPress and facing when adding code snippets (Java/Scala code). Whenever I add code snippet and choose `code`block in the blog, since width of code block is too small viewers of blogs have to horizontally scroll code. Its bit annoying because usually viewers would expect to see code without having to scroll horizontally (at least I don't like to scroll horizontally).

So my code block currently looks like below:

[image]

So I would like to know:

- if there is any way to reduce the font size of code block or
- if there is any way to increase width of code block or of entire blog itself?

Comment: These are likely all style changes that you can make to your theme (unless e.g. you're using a plugin on external website such as GitHub gists for your code samples, in which case you're probably using GitHub's styles). You probably should investigate the code block in your browsers debug tools and find out where its width is set or inherited from, ditto the font, and then try changing the styles there until you're happy; you can then customise this in the WordPress admin site theme customisation menu, or write a child theme that inherits from your current theme and changes those styles.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I didn't knew I had to write CSS just to increase width size of block . Why on earth they didn't gave any option to just increase width just like other tons of options they have? (sorry for taking out frustration)